# create file from function

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

# trims trailing spaces and tabs from file, using awk utility
function remove_trail() {

[ ! $# -lt 2 ] || { echo "Usage: $FUNCNAME file-to-trim out-file"; return 1; }

    # args
    in="$1"
    out="$2"

    # this check works fine...

    [ -f "$in" ] && return 0 || { echo "File \""$in"\" does not exist."; return 1; }

    # substitute tabs and spaces for nothing on $in arg, then output result to $out
    awk '{ sub(/[ \t]+$/, ""); print }' "$in" >tmp && mv tmp "$out"
    #however, after previous line I don't get my tmp file nor my $out file created.. WHY :O???
    # give user a friendly message
    echo 'Processing done.. Check your '"$out"' file.'
}
```

this function is defined in `.bashrc`, so I could use it daily as a kind of builtin.. so when I open shell I type remove_trail `file1` `file2` to get `file2` written from `file1`+removed_trailing_spaces.
My question is: Why I am not getting tmp and $out files created in my dir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the following line:

```
[ -f "$in" ] && return 0 || { echo "File \""$in"\" does not exist."; return 1; }
```

You `return` from the function if the `in` parameter to the function is a file.  This would explain the absence of the output file.

Perhaps you wanted to say:

```
[ -f "$in" ] || { echo "File \""$in"\" does not exist."; return 1; }
```

or

```
[ ! -f "$in" ] && { echo "File \""$in"\" does not exist."; return 1; }
```

---

Moreover, you wouldn't see the temp file as you move it to the output:

```
mv tmp "$out"
```

Comment: maaan.. i was starting to pull my hair off, that `return 0` was overseen totally. thanks ;)

Comment: yes of course for the `tmp` file, I know that, just thought that something with `mv` went wrong so I said, tmp or $out. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just write it as:

```
trim() { sed 's/[[:blank:]]*$//'; }
```

And use it as:

```
trim < file1 > file2
```

The rest is superfluous.

To prevent the output file being overwritten, you'd do:

```
trim() (
  set -C
  sed 's/[[:blank:]]*$//' > "$1"
)
```

and use it as:

```
trim < file1 file2
```

(note the absence of `>`).

You could also let `trim` open the input file, but you'd lose the ability to do things like:

```
cmd | trim out-file
```

Comment: I marked @devnull answer as a solution, because it gave solution for my script, I know i could use it shortway, but wanted to paractice my bash script skills ;).. But isn't downside of your approach that file2 would be silently overwritten if existed??

Comment: It would also be overwritten with your approach

Comment: yes you are right, i forgot i removed the line where i check for output file.. anyway thanks for your examples, i learned some things, why are you using braces in first case and parenthesis in another, () fires subshell and {} do not, but i don't see why are you using different ones in this example..

Comment: @branquito, to limit the scope of `set -C`.

Comment: ah ok, i thought of that but wasn't shure. anyway glad to meet you here, i read a lot of your examples going through bash guides (those where they say courtesy of Stephane Chazelas), lot of nice solutions.. ;)